# HTML form input text not showing

Tags: html, css, forms, text

My page is not showing the input text from my form. Whenever I select the text box, it glows but it does not accept text.

I know there's something wrong with my CSS, but I can't seem to figure out the problem.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="signin">
    <h2>Sign in</h2>
    <form method="post" action="index.html">
        <!-- <input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered"/> -->
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
        <br />
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="commit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    color: #fff;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    width: 55%;
    padding: 30px 0;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;

    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#signin, #close {
    display: none;
}

#signin {
    width: 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added `display : none` to `signin` id. Either make it `display : block` or remove it. Moreover for password field, `input type="password"` can be used.

Comment: I added this because I wanted to make a feature that will open the signin div once a button is clicked. It's original display is supposed to be none until the "sign in" button is pressed.

Comment: In that case, you can use javaScript or jQuery.

$('#buttonId').click(function() { 
$('#signin').css('display' , 'block');
});

Answer (score 0):

why did you do

```
 #signin, #close {
        display: none;
    }
```

try :

```
 #signin, #close {
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

```
#singin, #close {
    display: none;   
}
```

For:

```
#singin, #close {
    display: block; 
}
```

Or you can remove only.